# How to do a full length vertical split in tmux

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, tmux

I usually have two horizontal panes as such:

```
+–––––––––+–––––––––+
|                   |
|                   |  
|                   |
+–––––––––+–––––––––+
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
+–––––––––––––––––––+
```

**But would like to do a full-horizontal split like this**:

```
+–––––––––+–––––––––+
|         |         |
|         |         |  
|         |         |
+–––––––––|         |
|         |         |
|         |         |
|         |         |
+–––––––––––––––––––+
```

Whenever I do a split, it turns out like this:

```
+–––––––––+–––––––––+
|         |         |
|         |         |  
|         |         |
+–––––––––+–––––––––+
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
+–––––––––––––––––––+
```

So, I was wondering if there was a command that would do a full length vertical split. Thanks!

Edit: I forgot to mention that I wanted to only use one command to go from the first image to the second image.

Comment: Note: you described [horizontal split](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/213).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the [manual](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1#split-window) [emphasis mine]:

> ```
> split-window [-bdfhIvPZ] [-c start-directory] [-e environment] [-l size] [-t target-pane] [shell-command] [-F format]
> ```
>
> (alias: `splitw`)
>
> Create a new pane by splitting target-pane: `-h` does a horizontal split and `-v` a vertical split; if neither is specified, `-v` is assumed. […] The `-b` option causes the new pane to be created to the left of or above target-pane. **The `-f` option creates a new pane spanning the full window height (with `-h`) or full window width (with `-v`), instead of splitting the active pane.** […]

The tmux command you need is `split-window -hf`. You can bind it to a key like any other tmux command (e.g. `bind-key -T prefix ^ split-window -hf` in `~/.tmux.conf`; remember the file is read when you (re)start the tmux server or explicitly reload the file (<kbd>prefix</kbd><kbd>:</kbd>`source ~/.tmux.conf`<kbd>Enter</kbd>)).

In a shell the command will be this:

```
tmux split-window -hf
```

Answer (score 24):

You could do the following:

`ctrl + b + %` to make a vertical split.

`ctrl + b + "` to make a Horizontal split.

`ctrl + b + left arrow` to move to the left pane.

`ctrl + b + "` to make a Horizontal split.

and so you would have the four panels.

Comment: Thanks! I accidentally omitted some important notes, but I was looking for one command that would essentially do a full length vertical split.